# Why can the hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be represented by means of affine functions $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Why can the hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ can be represented by affine functions $\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Intuitively, it is true. But still, it is not clear for me.

An $n$-dimensional hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ defined by $(b,\beta)\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ can be represented as 
$$\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n | \langle x, b \rangle = \beta \}.$$
I also know that the hyperplane can also be represented as an affine function
$$\mathbb{R}^n \ni x \mapsto f(x)= \langle b, x\rangle - \beta.$$
Can someone help me deduce the first expression from the second?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

We can represent a hyperplane $\Pi \in \mathbb{R}^{n + 1}$ via a pair $(b, \beta) \in (\mathbb{R}^{n + 1} - \{0\}) \times \mathbb{R}$. Explicitly, $\Pi$ is the set
$$\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n + 1} : \langle b, x \rangle = \beta\}.$$

On the other hand, this is *precisely the zero set* of the affine function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n + 1} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$x \mapsto \langle b, x \rangle - \beta.$$

Conversely, any affine function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n + 1} \to \mathbb{R}$ can be written as
$$x \mapsto b_1 x_1 + \cdots b_{n + 1} x_{n + 1} - \beta$$ for (unique) coefficients $b_1, \ldots, b_{n + 1}, \beta$. If $f$ is nonconstant, then $b := (b_1, \ldots b_n)$ is nonzero, and
$$x \mapsto \langle b, x\rangle - \beta$$
defines a hyperplane.